# MongoMapper and Gmaps4Rails - Mapping location indexed array field to acts_as_gmappable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper, gmaps4rails

I have a model that's backed by Mongodb and I'm trying to get Gmaps4Rails to be able to properly use a location indexed array field that's in my mongo document.

I'm failing to figure out how I should map this given that the latitude and longitude aren't stored as independent values in order to take advantage of the geoindexing on mongo:

```
class Site
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  acts_as_gmappable :lat => ???,
                    :lon => ???,
                    :process_geocoding => false

  key :name, String
  key :location, Array
  ensure_index [[:location, '2d']]
end
```

for now I'm just doing this:

```
class Site
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false

  key :name, String
  key :location, Array
  ensure_index [[:location, '2d']]

  def lat
    return latitude
  end

  def lon
    return longitude
  end

  def latitude
    return location[1]
  end

  def longitude
    return location[0]
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you look at: `https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Mongoïd`

Comment: I did- issue is on mongo_mapper not mongoid. The Mongoid geo project says it has been dead for a year and I'm already on mapper so it seems like it would be nicer to get it working directly.

Comment: Ok I see. Sorry I've never touched mongo mapper but will be very insterested by your feedback to feed the wiki

Comment: What you've done seems like the right way to do it. If you don't want those extra methods cluttering up your model, pull them off into a module and then include it.